# Infinite Carousel with next and previous display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

Could Anyone help me to display the next set of Images in the infinite carousel

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/infinite-carousel.html

Ideally I would want the next set of images being displayed.I have had success in making some CRAPPY code for 2 panels(I assumed 3 Images as 1 Panel)...... could some one help me in making it dynamic (one that works for any number of panels) and clean unlike mine which is fiddled in the following URL

http://jsfiddle.net/adriancoopersfiddle/5yQ4y/

Sorry about the poor approach I am starter learning Javascript and HTML

Appreciate any help Thanks in Advance

Comment: This one http://jsfiddle.net/adriancoopersfiddle/r3AtT/ works for one cycle could someone please help me to make it infinite like the images

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out. 
http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/

it fits your description. 
 you can modify it to your exact requirement. 
This might help too 
http://jsfiddle.net/JCQ6Q/15/

vote up if it helps you. :) all the best